# How to set up cascading deletes in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, cascading-deletes

In MySQL Workbench, how do you set up a cascading delete on a relationship?

I clicked the *relationship line* and clicked on *properties* but I do not see any mention of a cascading delete option.

Comment: What version of MySql workbench are you using?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Right Click On Table -> Alter Table -> Foreign Keys Tab

Look at the upper-right corner "Foreign Key Options", there are two drop down boxes, one is to specify the delete action: "On Delete"

[image]

Comment: i dont understand why they dont add this to the other FK view too

Comment: It still helps in 2024. Thanks. :)